# Why does jQuery UI use CSS classes instead of pseudo-classes?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

As explained for example [here](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137970/jQuery%20UI%20CSS%20Framework), jQuery UI defines CSS classes like `.ui-state-active` (which are applied through JS), instead of using the existing CSS pseudo-classes, e.g. `:active`. Why?

Comment: Possibly because `:active` is [not fully supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#t40) in older versions of IE - remember that jQuery's primary purpose is to bridge compatibility problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon this recently, I found:

:active is mostly used for and implemented by different browsers for

`<a>` and `<button>`.

jQuery UI defines classes like .ui-state-active so that it can be easily applied to:

```
<ul>, <span>, <li>, <div>
```

As most of the jQuery UI elements are build up of these.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Answer (score 1):

Like Niet the Dark Absol said, the added class allows support for non HTML5 browsers like IE8 and below

http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.7/

> Better Support for HTML5 in IE6/7/8

According to can I use.com, iOS Safari and android doesn't support pseudo selectors either - So the added class allows browser compatibility for those devices

http://caniuse.com/#search=pseudo